# $cordovaFile.writeFile () throws an error always in ionic IOS whenever i try to click a picture and send an api request with it in ionic?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I use this code to click a picture and use google's `OCR api` on it to extract information. I installed all the necessary `Cordova` plugins. It works fine in android. Clicking picture is working fine while I try to write that image file this error is thrown.

**My Code Snippet :**

```
 $cordovaFile.writeFile(
                cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory,
                'file.json',
                file_contents,
                true
            ).then(function(result) {

                var headers = {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                };

                options.headers = headers;

                var server = 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=' + api_key;
                var filePath = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + 'file.json';

$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, filePath, options, true)
                    .then(function(result) {
                **//MY CODE COMES HERE**
                    }, function(err) {
                        alert('An error occured while uploading the file');
                    });

            }, function(err) {
                alert('An error occured while writing to the file');
            });**//THIS ERROR IS ALWAYS THROWN WITH CODE 3**

        }, function(err) {
            alert('An error occured getting the picture from the camera');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to build the same code for some tests and found out that the `cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory` is a read-only directory on iOS and Windows. So I traded it for `cordova.file.cacheDirectory` and it worked.

You can read more about CordovaFile [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) and read about the directory options of the cordova.file plugin [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file).